# Is there a way to select first on material-ui's autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete) has an autocomplete component however I couldn't find a way to auto select the first child. Is there?

Comment: Could you please clarify which first child are you talking about? Is it first match (filtered option) child of the first child of all the options?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text via the searchText prop. For example like this:

```
<AutoComplete
   searchText={dataSource1[0].text}
   dataSource={dataSource1}
/><br />


const dataSource1 = [
  {
    text: 'text-value1',
    value: (
     <MenuItem
      primaryText="text-value1"
      secondaryText="&#9786;"
     />
    ),
  },
  {
    text: 'text-value2',
    value: (
     <MenuItem
      primaryText="text-value2"
      secondaryText="&#9786;"
     />
    ),
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the renderInput and send the 'enter' trigger by onKeyPress, where you use a state to active the useEffect to get the first li of ul:

```
renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label=""
            variant="outlined"
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              style: { paddingTop: '1.275px', paddingBottom: '1.275px' },
              **onKeyPress: e => setEnterClick(e.code),**
              endAdornment: (
                <>
                  {!options.length ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                  {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                </>
              )
            }}
          />
        )}
```

the state is enterClick:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const optionElements = document?.querySelector('[data-option-index="0"]');

    if (enterClick === 'Enter' && optionElements) {
      optionElements.current?.parentNode.click();
      setEnterClick('');
    }
  }, [enterClick]);
```